# Process a jQuery $Post with php?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to process this with php (note that the data being sent is JSON):

```
$.post("calculate.php", existingJsonData,
    function(data) {
    //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    console.log("test data", data.values);
});
```

The existingJsonData is formatted like this:

```
{
    "object1": {
        "object11": {"x": "10", "y": "20", "z": "30"}, 
        "object12": {"x": "40", "y": "50", "z": "60"}, 
        "object13": {"x": "70", "y": "80", "z": "90"}
  }, 
    "object2": {
      "object21": {"x": "100", "y": "200", "z": "300"}, 
      "object22": {"x": "400", "y": "500", "z": "600"}, 
      "object23": {"x": "700", "y": "800", "z": "900"}
    }
}
```

The php needs to add  1 to each of the x's in "object2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one adds 1 to each of the x's in object 2 and alerts you the incremented values

```
<?php 
if ($_POST){ 
    ob_clean(); 
    $objects = $_POST['object2']; 
    foreach($objects as $a => $subObject) { 
        $objects[$a] = $subObject['x'] + 1; 
    }  
    die(json_encode((object) $objects)); 
} 

?> 
<script> 
var existingJsonData=  $.parseJSON('{    "object1": {        "object11": {"x": "10", "y": "20", "z": "30"},         "object12": {"x": "40", "y": "50", "z": "60"},        "object13": {"x": "70", "y": "80", "z": "90"} },  "object2": { "object21": {"x": "100", "y": "200", "z": "300"},  "object22": {"x": "400", "y": "500", "z": "600"}, "object23": {"x": "700", "y": "800", "z": "900"}}}');
$.post("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>", existingJsonData, 
    function(data) { 
    var data = $.parseJSON(data); 
    $.each(data, function(a,b){ 
       alert(a+' : '+b); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/e2b63)

Comment: Thanks for this. Should the PHP file include something like---> echo json_encode($objects);

Comment: @JohnR: I have spent a lot of time with testing this, hope you like it

Comment: Can`t you just POST it after you have serialize it and then unserialize?

Comment: @KA_lin: I can, but why? It does the same thing